# Check whether the series converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{2}-43}$ converges?

I tried to show by comparission test.
I got $0<\frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{2}}<\frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{2}-43}$ for $n>10$.
But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{2}}$ converges.
I am unabe to proceed so on...
Can i do same way or i have to go for another test?

Comment: I doubt $ \ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{-5/2} \ $ converges, given what the first term is.  You will have to start from $ \ n \ = \ 1 \ $ in making comparisons either by the basic comparison or limit comparison tests, and hold the $ \ n \ = \ 0 \ $ term in your series separate.

Comment: Sorry! Its my mistake. From n=1.

Comment: Your series for comparison is fine, but you'll likely want the limit comparison test, instead of a direct comparison.  **Henrik**'s suggestion of finding a constant to multiply $ \ \frac{1}{n^{5/2}} \ $ by in order to make a direct comparison work in the "right direction" is also a possibility.

Comment: The first four terms of the series are negative.then how can we apply limit comparisson test? The limit comparission test is aplocable for seies with positive terms no?

Comment: That doesn't make any difference for the convergence of an infinite series: we are only concerned with what happens for the sum of the terms _beyond_ some finite partial sum.  You would apply the limit comparison test for the terms starting at $ \ n \ = \ 5 \ $ for the two series, then note that the first four terms of your series have a finite sum.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps directly apply the *limit comparison test*:

$$\frac{\frac1{n^{5/2}-43}}{\frac1{n^{5/2}}}=\frac{n^{5/2}}{n^{5/2}-43}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

and thus our series converges since $\;\sum\frac1{n^5/2}\;$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that $n^{5/2}-43>n^{9/4}$ for $n$ sufficiently big since

$$\frac{n^{5/2}-43}{n^{9/4}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} +\infty.$$

So

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac 1{n^{5/2}-43}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1{n^{9/4}}.$$

And the second series converges because of the Riemann example : $\frac 94>1$.

Comment: Is this correct???  I think your inequality is wrong.

Comment: This series has a couple surprises in it: the given series terms change sign after $ \ n \ = \ 4 \ $ and then the terms are positive and _larger_ than $ \ \frac{1}{n^{5/2}} \ $ .  A little more care (and perhaps the limit comparison test) is needed.

Comment: You were absolutely right, i edited. Thanks for the remarks.

Comment: @ElioJoseph I'm afraid it is still wrong, or even more than before, since $\;n^{5/2}-43\color{red}< n^3\;$ for almost all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ ...

Comment: Sorry again for my miscalculation. I edited again.

Comment: First of all, $$\frac{n^{5/2}-43}{n^{9/2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$ The rest needs to take this into account.

Comment: I am making an awful lot of mistakes today... I edited.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison test should be good enough, you'll just need to do something to get rid of the $43$. You can either shift the series or find some constant you can multiply the terms with (hint: $5^{\frac52}>43$) that you can put in instead.

Comment: By which term i have to multiply?

Comment: Look for a constant $ \ C \ $ that will make $ \ C \ \frac{1}{n^{5/2}} \ > \ \frac{1}{n^{5/2} \ - \ 43 } \ $ for some  value of $ \ n \ $ and greater  .